# N-Queens Algorithm using c++

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to solve the N-Queens Problem using C++ but I am not getting the proper output, maybe my **is_attacked()** function have some problems. Please help me in improving my code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int N;
int board[10][10] = {0};

//to check attacking position
bool is_attacked(int row, int col) {
for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
{
    if(board[row][i] == 1 || board[i][col] == 1)
        return true;
}
if(row >= 1)
    if(board[row-1][col-1] == 1 || board[row-1][col+1] == 1)
        return true;

return false;
}
//to print the values
void print()
{
  for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<N;++j)
    {
        cout << board[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
}
//to solve the problem
bool solve(int n) 
{
   if(n == 0)
     return true;
   //main logic, i => row, j => columns
   for(int i=0; i < n; ++i)
   {
     for(int j=0; j<n; ++j)
     {

        if(is_attacked(i, j))
            continue;
        board[i][j] = 1;
        if(solve(n-1))
            return true;
        board[i][j] = 0;

      }
    }
  return false;
}

int main() {
 cin >> N;
 //let's add some basic_cases
  if(N == 2 || N == 3)
  {    cout << "Not possible";
       exit(0);
  }
  if(solve(N))
     print();
  else 
     cout << "Not Possible";
  return 0;
}
```

Its should display

```
0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0
```

but I am getting

```
1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1
```

Please help me... Thanks in advance...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [ask]. Questions that just post a block of code and ask us to debug it for you are off-topic here.

Comment: What attempts have you made to debug?  Have you tried putting print statements in the code to verify your assumptions at various points?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. You can also test each part of the code separately to figure out exactly which part of the code is causing the problem, and make a [mcve]. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. Debugging your own code is an important skill in programming. See http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/.

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic but I am new to programming, I just wanted some help that's why I posted the question... Hope you all will understand this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part in is_attaced in which you check the diagonals is not working. It has two basic problems, first you dont check all diagonals all rows - you just check the previous row. And, second, you are doing out of bound accesses, when you are in the first or last column.

An implementation that is not realy efficient but easy to understand check the both diagonals seperately

```
for( int i=min(col, row); i>0;i-- )
{
   if( board[row-i][col-i]==1 )
      return true;
}
for( int i=MAX_COL; i>row;i-- )
{
   if( board[row-i][col+i]==1 )
      return true;
}
```

A better way would be doing both in one loop.

Comment: Thanks for helping me.